# Repairing a perfect binary merkle forest

Tags: algorithms, optimization, binary-trees

Let's say we have a forest of imperfect binary merkle trees of different heights (this is an invariant). Only the numbered nodes store data, the rest store hashes. Here is an example with 4 trees, with heights 3, 2, 1, 0. Laid out with the leaves at the bottom, non-leaf roots labeled with letters:

```
A
|---------------\
*               *               B
|-------\                       |-------\
*       *                       *       *       C  
|---\   |---\                           |---\   |---\
0   1   2   3                           10  11  12  13  14
```

My goal is to move nodes (with their children), such that the result is a new
forest of *perfect* binary merkle trees of different sizes. Since every number can be factored into exponents of 2, any amount of leaves can be "missing", and the rebalancing can still work.

### Example rebalancing

Lets add names to all nodes, and fill the the tree with dummy data so that we can talk about nodes conveniently. L for left-child, R for right-child:

```
A
|---------------\
AL              AR              B
|-------\       |-------\       |-------\
ALL     ARR     ARL     ALL     BL      BR      C  
|---\   |---\   |---\   |---\   |---\   |---\   |---\
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14
```

Let's call the function `rebalance`, and its first argument a set of nodes to delete, and the second is the amount of leaves that the tree has.

I now propose a solution for the example `rebalance(nodes=[AR, BL], leaves_in_forest=15)`. AR and BL are the trees that prevent the forest from being perfect. This could be a result of the algorithm:

- Lowest row: Swap nodes 14 and 4.
- Second lowest row: Swap node C and BL.
- Third lowest row: Swap node B and AR.
- Rehash the nodes whose children changed since starting swapping, bottom-up: B and then A.

In code, this candidate solution can be encoded in a tuple, returned from the function:

- the sequence of swaps: `14,4`, `C,BL`, `B,AR`
- the rehashes, bottom-up: B, A (I will explain how this is derived below)

To demonstrate that the solution is valid, here is the forest after the swapping, using the old names for the hashes/leaves, so one can see where they ended up:

```
A
|---------------\
AL              B               AR
|-------\       |-------\       |-------\
ALL     ARR     C       BR      ARL     ALL     BL  
|---\   |---\   |---\   |---\   |---\   |---\   |---\
0   1   2   3   12  13  10  11  14  5   6   7   8   9   4
```

The 'phantom' nodes 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4 are now at the end, and they were to be discarded. We can reduce the forest to the tree A and the odd leaf 14:

```
A
|---------------\
AL              B
|-------\       |-------\
ALL     ARR     C       BR
|---\   |---\   |---\   |---\
0   1   2   3   12  13  10  11  14
```

We have done the 3 swaps. But we also need to rehash some nodes, to maintain the invariant that each non-leaf hashes its children. But which nodes do we need to rehash? Let's cover all nodes, bottom-up, left-to-right:

- No nodes on the two lower rows had their children changed.
- Third lowest row:

  - AL didn't change, but B did, since its children were previously BL and BR, now they are C and BR. So it must be rehashed.
- Fourth lowest row:

  - A did change since it's children are now AL and B, previously it was AL and AR. So it must be rehashed.

In total, we need 2 hashes: B and A.

### Does this forest still meet the invariants?

1. Yes, it is a forest of differently-sized perfect binary merkle trees. It has 8+1=9 leaves. The binary representation of 9 is 1001, which has two bits set. Therefore we have two trees in the forest.
2. Yes, every node must hash its children, since we checked every node.

### How expensive was the proposed solution for `rebalance(nodes=[AR, BL] leaves_in_forest=15)`?

2 swaps + 2 hashes.

### My question

How can I implement `rebalance`? I have been looking at tree balancing algorithms, but they do not consider that the tree could be a merkle tree and hashing should be minimized.